# will using Expo worst in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I am new in react native. when i create react native app by :`create-react-native-app My project name` the project will create with some thing named Expo in it directory.

then when i run it in emulator it will running by expo and i having to see an app named Expo and i have to run my app by using that. **Ok**?

i did many search a bout Expo and saw that site, and many other sites and notes which were about Expo but i understood nothing, just Expo will make it Easy to run your app.

now i want to ask: if i use expo; will my clients have to use that for running my app on their devices??

and ask: will i have to pay money for some essential things in future ?(Given that i never  want to pay any thing )

will Expo make my application depending on himself(Expo) and prevent me to use various APIs like google map or ?

and in last: **using that or not**? **which way is more professional?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, welcome to the React Native community!

Most of these questions can be answered in the [Expo FAQ](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq.html)

---

> if i use expo; will my clients have to use that for running my app on their devices??

You can at any time [detach](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/detach.html#content) your app from expo and publish it to the App Store or Android Play Store.

---

> will i have to pay money for some essential things in future ?(Given that i never want to pay any thing )

From the expo FAQ page: "**Expo is free**.
Our plan is to keep it this way indefinitely.
Expo is also open source, so you don’t have to trust us to stick to that plan.
We might eventually charge money for services built on top of Expo or for some kind of premium level of support and consulting."

---

> will Expo make my application depending on himself(Expo) and prevent me to use various APIs like google map or ?

Assuming you are talking about [`Native Modules`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html).

Expo provides a very large API for building a native app.

Some known reasons you might detach are:

- Using a companies Proprietary internal native API
- Unsupported libraries like React Native Fetch Blob - this is currently being added to React Native but until then it is not available in Expo

If you do need to add custom Native Modules, you could always detach from expo. When you Detach you will get an ios, and a android project.

Lastly you could always recommend new features: https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests

---

> and in last: using that or not? which way is more professional?

Using Expo will provide you with tested Native Modules on top of React Native, if anything this makes it more professional.

Here are some popular apps constructed with [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/showcase.html).